# structure of img directory react.js

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs

How on earth do i get images to display? 40 mins reaserching and still no joy. I think the real answer is where do i put images.

structure of the main dir

```
App.js
public > index.js 
Views >
      index.jsx
      layouts >
          footer.jsx
          header.jsx
          master.jsx
```

Wherever i put the images they won't display. the main file that gets called and renders the html is index.jsx inside the views folder.

I am using express to create the virtual server and as the core engine.

i have tried the following inside the header.jsx file

```
<img src='images/main_home_icon.png'/>
<img src={require('images/main_home_icon.png')} />
```

Comment: The directory structure doesn't have a whole lot to do with it. The URLs of the images and the URLs of the pages are determined by your Node.js code.

Comment: BINGO, wow, simple stuff is so complex, SO to solve the issue had to declare this in express "app.use(express.static('./public'));"

Comment: "simple stuff" — Writing your own webserver in JavaScript isn't really what I'd call "simple".

Comment: simple as in all i wanted to do was call an image ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends. If you use the `<img src='images/main_home_icon.png'/>` form, then your base path is the public directory. Normally you create a bundle.js with browserify or webpack and put the javascript file in a directory with an index file. You would then have to put the images in the same directory.

On the other hand you can include your images directly in your javascript code with:

`<img src={require('images/main_home_icon.png')} />`

Then your base path is the base path of the jsx file (in your case: layouts folder). I would advise to use this method because you can define e.g. in your webpack config which images (depends on their size) should be included in your bundle file as a base64 string and which are included only with their relative path.

For further reading I would suggest to take a look at this "cookbook": https://github.com/christianalfoni/react-webpack-cookbook

Comment: Excellent, Thank you so much for a resource rich site, it's been really frustrating trying to graple with the basics, its not just the syntax its the whole structure top to bottom. double thumbs up